# Move function from ViewController to swift file so it's reusable

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a function to change the label text color on several labels that are part of an outlet collection.

I want to move this function from the view controller to a project file so I can reuse it.

How do I replace the reference to `self` and pass the proper view conroller and outlet collection to the function?

```
func setLabelColor() {

    var counter = 0
    let myColor = UIColor.white
    while counter < labelOutletCollection.count {

        self.labelOutletCollection[counter].textColor = myColor

        counter += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may move this code to a separate file where you store your globally usable functions and make the array of labels a parameter.

```
func setLabelColor(_ labels: [UILabel]) {
    var counter = 0
    let myColor = UIColor.white

    while counter < labels.count {
        labels[counter].textColor = myColor

        counter += 1
    }
}
```

On another node, this code can be much cleaner by replacing it with a single `forEach` statement:

```
labels.forEach { $0.textColor = .white }
```

You can use this function like this:

```
setLabelColor(labelOutletCollection)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try the for loop it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a extension at the button of your ViewController and then call it whenever you want.

```
extension:ViewController{
    func setLabelColor(myArray:[UILabel]) {

       var counter = 0
       let myColor = UIColor.white
       while counter < myArray.count {

             myArray[counter].textColor = myColor

             counter += 1
        }
       }
}
```

then you can just say

```
myVC.setLabelColor(myArray: labelOutletCollection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
/////// Example :
@IBOutlet var testlbl: [UILabel]
viewController.setLabelColor(testlbl)
```

Actual function :

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setLabelColor(_ labels: [UILabel]) {
        var counter = 0
        let myColor = UIColor.white

        while counter < labels.count {
            labels[counter].textColor = myColor

            counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of the working function. Many thanks to the4kman.

```
import UIKit

func setLabelColor(setColor: UIColor, collection: [UILabel]) {

for label in collection {

    label.textColor = setColor

   }
}
```

Call the func from your ViewController (MyOutLetCollection is an Outlet Collection):

```
setLabelColor(setColor: UIColor.white, collection: MyOutletCollection)
```